# Woo-commerce get_shipping_method_class_names() not getting all active classes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating my custom word-press plugin try to get all active classes or active shipping like (FedEx,UPS,USPS) in my project these all three plugin is active when i try to get using below code :

```
$shipping_methods_classes  = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_method_class_names();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($shipping_methods_classes);die;
```

it`s getting only FedEx , remaining two UPS, USPS not getting

**output --**

```
Array
(
    [flat_rate] => WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate
    [free_shipping] => WC_Shipping_Free_Shipping
    [local_pickup] => WC_Shipping_Local_Pickup
    [0] => wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping_method
)
```

and when I write this code into header.php then its working fine, but on my custom plugin not getting all results.

Comment: Have you tried running the code on the `woocommerce_loaded` hook?

Comment: i didn`t try using that, how can we use this ?

Comment: Nevermind, that seems irrelevant now. Are you sure you have another shipping method active?

Comment: well, thanks i got solution...

Comment: Please post your solution for future readers. Also, in re-reading your question, if you can't get the active info in your plugin then I have to circle back to `woocommerce_loaded`. The `header.php` template is loaded well after all the plugins are loaded and so there is no question that WooCommerce is fully loaded and you can `var_dump()` things in there that may not appear if you are calling them directly in a plugin file, unless the function (and ideally the entire plugin) isn't loaded until WC is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

ITs Done By --

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_shipping_init');

function woocommerce_shipping_init() {
  if (class_exists('WC_Shipping')) {
    $shipping = new WC_Shipping();

    $shipping_classes = array();
    /* this return all services */
    $shipping_classes = $shipping->get_shipping_method_class_names();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($shipping_classes);die;
  } else {
    add_action('admin_notices', 'woocomeerce_plugin_activation_error');
  }
}
```

**Output --**

```
Array
(
    [flat_rate] => WC_Shipping_Flat_Rate
    [free_shipping] => WC_Shipping_Free_Shipping
    [local_pickup] => WC_Shipping_Local_Pickup
    [0] => wf_fedex_woocommerce_shipping_method
    [1] => WF_Shipping_UPS
    [2] => WF_Shipping_USPS
)
```